# Zapier-dalać includes u' on Action Fields (Custom) fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, field, action, zapier

```
{u'UDF_USER1': u'660759063'}

action_fields": {
    "UDF_USER1": "660759063", 
    "UDF_DATE1": "09-20-2018 04:57:40 PM", 
    "UDF_CHAR1": "sdfsdf", 
    "UDF_TEXT1": "akjhdkaljdhasdkjas", 
    "UDF_CHAR2": "asdasdas"
}
```

when I set params through `bundle.action_fields_full.<somekey> = bundle.action_fields`   It appends `'u` in json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found why `u'`

When doing a POST request in a write action, you may see Python unicode artifacts in your payload. For example:

```
[{u'lastName': u'Wayne', u'firstName': u'Bruce'}]
```

This mean you're passing an object to bundle.request.data, which expects a string. Call JSON.stringify on your data object in the ACTION_KEY_pre_write method.

ref: 
 [unicode artifacts](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/scripting/#key_custom_action_fields)